# Is there a limit on bringing my videogames?

Tags: airlines, airport-security, lax

So far, I wanted to go on a trip with my gaming Console (PS4) And my family to the Philippines this Sunday, but I wanted to bring my videogames (cd’s) like at least 7-8 of them, but I worry that there are limits to bring. Like going through the check point, and I’m afraid that they will take it away, and it would be a waste of money.[image]

Comment: Where do you leave from?

Comment: You should have no problem with say 10 or so such CDs.

Answer (score 3):

For most countries you will have no problems at all. as a visitor you can bring in most things if they are for personal use and you intend to take them with you when you leave (obvious exception being anything illegal). Certainly ten or so game CDs will not be a problem.